Errror when writing a function that uses a mids object and gtsummary
I'm conducting linear regression analysis with a variety of exposures and outcomes.
Each analysis has 3 models and uses a imputed dataset created with mice().
I'm trying to create a function in which I can specificy only the outcome and exposure variables, and it gives me the result table with all the models using gtsummary, but I'm getting the error that the outcome variable is not found.
I suspect it has something to do with the way that the function handles mids object, but couldn't find a solution.
library(mice)
#> Warning: package 'mice' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
library(gtsummary)
#> Warning: package 'gtsummary' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> #BlackLivesMatter

mtcars <- mtcars
mtcars[2,"gear"] <- NA
mtcars[6,"vs"] <- NA

imp_mtcars <- mice(mtcars, m = 4, maxit = 1)
#> 
#>  iter imp variable
#>   1   1  vs  gear
#>   1   2  vs  gear
#>   1   3  vs  gear
#>   1   4  vs  gear

generate_models <- function(imp_df, outcome_var, exposure_var) {
  require(mice)
  require(gtsummary)
  
  # Base model with just the exposure
  m0 <- with(imp_df, lm(paste(outcome_var, "~", exposure_var))) %>% 
    tbl_regression() %>% 
    add_glance_table(include = c(adj.r.squared))
  
  # Adjusted model 1
  m1 <- with(imp_df, lm(paste(outcome_var,"~", exposure_var, "+ vs"))) %>%
    tbl_regression() %>%
    add_glance_table(include = c(adj.r.squared))
  
  # Adjusted model 2
  m2 <- with(imp_df, lm(paste(outcome_var,"~", exposure_var, "+ vs + gear"))) %>%
    tbl_regression(include = exposure_var) %>%
    add_glance_table(include = c(adj.r.squared))
  
  # Combine the tables
  tbl_global <- tbl_merge(list(m0, m1, m2),tab_spanner = c("**Unadjusted**", "**Model 1**", "**Model 2**"))
  
  return(tbl_global)
}

generate_models(imp_mtcars, "mpg", "hp")
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): objeto 'mpg' não encontrado

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

It looks like you're passing imp_mtcars, but mpg and hp aren't column names of imp_mtcars.  They're column names of mtcars

I managed to solve it. The with function creates an environment to iterate over the many datasets contained in the mids object.
I put the model formula inside {} so it could be read in this environment and used as.formula to make it clear that the expression was a formula and it worked.
# Analyzing each imputed dataset directly within with()
  m0 <- with(imp_df, {
    lm(as.formula(paste(outcome_var, "~", exposure_var)))}) %>%
      tbl_regression() %>%
      add_glance_table(include = c(adj.r.squared))

